# unknown error: Cannot read property 'style' of null in webdriver

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

I've seen this on other posts, but none seemed to help.

code:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("upload_iframe_1");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);
JavascriptExecutor executor= (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("document.querySelector('div.clear new_Passport_form qEgULQ some-margin togglable').style.display='block';");
```

html code :

```
<div class="fl f18 dtoggler pointer underline some-padding new_data_entry" data-div-id="qEgULQ" data-div-ref="new_Passport_form.qEgULQ">
+ Add Passport
</div>
<div class="clear new_Passport_form qEgULQ some-margin togglable" style="display: block;">
```

I am getting error as:  unknown error: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Comment: `document.querySelector('div.clear new_Passport_form qEgULQ some-margin togglable')` looks like an invalid selector

Comment: If you want to use `CSS` selector you need to separate each `class` name with a dot, like `div.clear.new_Passport_form.qEgULQ.some-margin.togglable` while in `XPath` you can use it in same way as it appears in `HTML`: `//div[@class="clear new_Passport_form qEgULQ some-margin togglable"]`

Comment: @Andersson getting same error unknown error: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Comment: @Gausiafatima, This means that there is no element `div` with compound class name `"clear new_Passport_form qEgULQ some-margin togglable"`. As I've mentioned in your previous ticket, some `class` names could be assigned dynamically, so one of class names could be absent initially. You can try to use another selector